# How to achieve the find and replace following task?

Tags: regex

I have a string pattern like  "test" : "abc/gef fhhff/fhrhr krerjr",

I would like to replace all space in the line beginning with "test" with plus sign. How to do that using regular expression?

Comment: Since regexes by themselves do not have replace capability, it depends on what tool you are using.  Perl?  Java? C#?  Sed?  Ed?

Comment: *[user705414](http://stackoverflow.com/users/705414/user705414)*: You should format the code (in this case the string) as it is not clear whether the quotes are part of the string or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for vb net try

```
        Dim strCurrentLine as string = "test : abc/gef fhhff/fhrhr krerjr"

        If UCase(strCurrentLine.ToString.StartsWith("TEST")) = True Then
            strCurrentLine = Replace(strCurrentLine.ToString, " ", "Replace space with this text")
        End If
```

for C# try

```
    string strCurrentLine = "test : abc/gef fhhff/fhrhr krerjr";

    if (Strings.UCase(strCurrentLine.ToString().StartsWith("TEST")) == true) {
        strCurrentLine = Strings.Replace(strCurrentLine.ToString(), " ", "Replace space with this text");
    }
```

or go here for vb regex http://visualbasic.about.com/od/usingvbnet/a/RegExNET_2.htm

or go here for c# regex http://oreilly.com/windows/archive/csharp-regular-expressions.html

Answer (score 0):

In perl you have to do something like:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use 5.010;

my $text = q|test : "abc/gef fhhff/fhrhr krerjr"|;

#below is the regex that does the replace - \s is for whitespace class
$text =~ s/\s/+/gmix if ( $text =~ /^test/gmix);

say "new text: $text";
```